# Problems with Backbone jQuery loading order

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In one of my views I am pulling in a collection (user_id, date, # of posts, avg post length) and then performing some math calculations on the data (ex: aggregate the total number and avg post length.

To do this I am looping through using an underscore each function and creating a new view (element is a tr) that is appended to a table.

At the end of the loop I am calling the jquery sort table plugin to sort the data in the table.  The problem I'm running into is that a lot of times the each loop hasn't finished running before I call the jQuery sort table. I have set it up so there is a delay before the jquery is called, but what is a more elegant solution that will work 100% of the time in this scenario.

```
var size = _.size(userposts);
_.each(userposts, function(post) {

  var sum = 0;
  var totposts = 0;
  j++;
  _.each(post, function(times) {
    sum += (times.get("posts") * times.get("avgpost"));
    totposts += times.get("posts");
  });

  if(post[0].get("userId")){
    var tempuser = new User({id: post[0].get("userId")});
    tempuser.fetch({ success: function() {
      $("#user-posts").append(new UserPostView({data: {name: tempuser.get("name"), num: totposts, avg: parseInt((sum / totposts))}}).render().el);
    }});
  }
  if (j == size) {
    formatTable();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly is the async part in the steps you're describing?

Comment: Are you performing async task in the iterator function of each? To help you further, paste the code here.

Comment: I added the code from the each loop

Answer (score 0):

So, perhaps I am missing your questions, but to lay it all out, you have:

a loop (or a collection of loops)

an event that needs to fire at the end of the loop?

A timer is a big no no! What if this process takes longer on other computers? Or a mobile device? You never want to rely on timers to queue up function calls that rely on pre existing data, especially not without a backup.

There are 2 ways I can think of doing this

```
var loopStatus = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
someMethod();

loopStatus++

if (loopStatus = n){
 someMethod2();

}

}
```

or you could just use a while with the someMethod2() call at the end of it, outside the loop

Comment: I tried this (code shown above) but I'm still running into the same problem. I think it has to do with the fetch that occurs to get the user name and that is taking longer than to call the jquery in the format tables function.